# C# WinForms Application exits unexpectedly with no exception, but only when the API piece is not on the same machine

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

I am developing an application which is to run as a WinForms thick-client, accessing both an API to be running in the cloud (Azure), and a local SQL Server DB for data.

To allow users to log in, the login screen is triggered as a Modal prompt when the application starts up with the following code in the HomeScreen form which is the 'main' page of the application:

```
 using (Form loginScreen = new LoginForm())
                {
                    loginScreen.ShowDialog(this);
                }
```

Once the login screen has been passed, the user can see the home screen, if they cancel it, the application closes. Once they get to the home screen, another API call is run to retrieve data about the user from the API for display on the home screen.

All API calls execute the same code, which is below (this is very early code for a 'working prototype' and I am aware there are probably issues with it that require a refactor, at this point I'm really only interested in understanding what is causing my call to PostAsJsonAsync to fail:

```
  public async Task<ApiResponse> sendApiRequest(RequestDetail reqDet)
        {
            //create a variable to track if the action was done or we need to retry after a timeout and login
            bool actionDone = false;

            //instantiate a variable for the ApiResponse so it can be used later outside of the scope of the actionDone loop
            ApiResponse res = null;
            while (actionDone == false)
            {
                //populate the main SessionKey of the packet from the GlobalData var (for initial dev, to be refactored out)
                reqDet.SessionKey = GlobalData.SessionKey;
                //populate the SessionKey in the array underneath the main object (for future use)
                reqDet.strParameters["SessionKey"] = GlobalData.SessionKey;
               
                //instantiate a new ApiRequest object to hold the main request body
                ApiRequest req = new ApiRequest("ClientRequest", reqDet);
                
                //Create HttpClient class for communication with the server
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                //Set URL and Headers (URL will be in a config file in future
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://removed.the.url.for.se/api/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                //actually call the service, wait for the response, and read it out into the response object
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync((string)req.requestBody.ApiLocation, req); 
                res = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResponse>();
                
                //check if the response was successful or we need to show an error
                if (res.responseType == "Success")
                {
                    //set action done to TRUE so we exit the loop   
                    actionDone = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    //Use the MessageService to dispaly the error
                    Error err = res.responseError;
                    MessagesService ms = new MessagesService();
                    await ms.displayErrorPrompt(err);

                    //trigger a login screen and restart the service call if the user's session has expired
                    if (err.ErrorText.Equals("Session has expired, please log in again"))
                    {
                        using (Form login = new LoginForm())
                        {
                            login.ShowDialog();
                        } // Dispose form
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // set ActionDone to True if it's not a login error so we don't endlessly call the service
                        actionDone = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            //return the final result
            return res;
        }
```

When running the entire stack locally, this all works perfectly, I can login and traverse the rest of my application as normal. When running the client locally in VS and the API in Azure, the first call to the Login API succeeds (I can call it multiple times e.g. with a wrong password and it behaves as normal), however the second call to get the user's data to paint on the home screen fails.If I put a breakpoint on the PostAsJsonAsync line, I can see that the line executes once and continues as normal, but immediately after stepping over the line the second time for the user details call, the entire application exits without executing the subsequent code.

What is strange about this is that it exits with a 0x0 return code, does not throw an exception, or in any way behave abnormally other than shutting down after just that line.

I have tried manually calling the APIs on the Azure service in Postman and they all return exactly the same (correct) results I get when running it locally, so I know it is not the deployment to the App Service that is the issue.

**Things I have tried to fix it after Googling, reading other SE posts and looking at comments on this question**

- I have tried enabling first-chance exceptions in Visual Studio for all CLR exceptions. Nothing is caught or thrown that I can see.
  [Here is a screenshot of my settings in case I've done something wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lohI.png)
- I have tried wrapping just that line in a try-catch block that catches all exceptions. It still immediately stops executing after the PostAsJsonAsync and never reaches the Catch block
- Adding the following code to my Program.cs file to catch unhandled exceptions (is never run when I put a breakpoint on it and nothing is written to the console that I can see):

```
 static void Main()
        {
            AppDomain currentDomain = AppDomain.CurrentDomain;
            currentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(MyHandler);
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new HomeScreen());
        }

        static void MyHandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
        {
            Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
            Console.WriteLine("MyHandler caught : " + e.Message);
        }
```

- Setting a DumpFolder that is writable by all users, and a DumpType of 2 in a key named after my executable at Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps\ - I've tried both keys named MyApplication and MyApplication.exe and neither results in a file being produced when the app crashes.
- The Windows Event Viewer after the 'crash' (nothing from my application)
- Reviewing the request/response in Fiddler - the first 'login' request and response is shown correctly, but the second is not shown at all, so it looks like it's crashing before even sending the request

I'd be extremely grateful for any suggestions you can provide, even if it is only a workaround or 'patch' to resolve the issue. It's extremely strange to me both that it exits the program with no exception and without running the subsequent code, that it only does this when the API piece is running in Azure, not when running locally, and finally that it's only when it gets to the subsequent request after the login.

**Update**
I have tried commenting out the line that runs the RefreshScreen() function to call the web service again and the application still exits in the same way after the login, but just without hitting my breakpoint a second time. However again only when the application is running against the Azure API and not locally. If I break at the last line of the HomeScreen constructor and keep stepping, it goes back to my Main() method and ends the application. Is there something I'm doing wrong here?

I think the PostAsJsonAsync may have been a red herring so have taken it out of the title.

```
             public HomeScreen()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            if(GlobalData.SessionKey == null)
            {
                using (Form loginScreen = new LoginForm())
                {
                    loginScreen.ShowDialog(this);
                } 
                // Dispose form
            }
            refreshScreen();
        }

        public async Task refreshScreen()
        {
            ApiService srv = new ApiService();
            ApiResponse res =  await srv.sendApiRequest(new Sessions_GetUserDetailsRequest());
            if (res.responseType == "Success")
            {
                foreach (dynamic usrItem in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(res.responseContent))
                {
                    lblUserName.Text =  usrItem.UserGivenName + " " + usrItem.UserSurname;
                    lblSiteName.Text = usrItem.TenantName;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can use Fiddler to intercept the traffic coming back from Azure and inspect it. I am guessing that the data coming back is some type of error information instead of the ApiResponse that you are expecting (by saying res = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ApiResponse>();), and .NET is breaking with an unhandled exception because it can't deserialize the response

Comment: Hi Joon, thanks for your response. I've checked the API in Postman and it returns the same as when run locally, but I'll do a check in Fiddler to be sure.

Comment: Sure thing! Remember that postman will use your web browser proxy settings by default (if you are on a corporate network), and .NET won't unless you edit the app.config to tell it what proxy to use. If the proxy is the error, using Fiddler might make it start working automatically. If that's the case, then you know the proxy is the problem ;-)

Comment: No proxy on my network - I've tried Fiddler and it looks like it's crashing before even sending the request, as the first one shows up with the correct request/response but the second one doesn't at all.

Comment: @Joon I think the Json stuff is a red herring, as after removing that line from the main screen the app still crashes - please see my update to the answer - I've included code from my window constructor to see if that helps...

Comment: I can't quite tell from the code sample, are you creating one Winform in the constructor of another Winform? Generally that is bad practice, you would be better off using the OnShow event to perform your processing. You may be freaking the .NET framework out by creating and showing a form while constructing the first one hasn't finished yet.

Comment: Just thought of something else - if you run the app from the command line instead of from inside Visual Studio, does it print anything to the console?

Comment: Thanks - yes I was running in the constructor and moved it to an OnLoad event at your suggestion and also tried running in the command line, both didn't give me a solution (though I'll leave the code in the OnLoad event if that's the better place for it). However, the digging I had to do has led me to the fact that it's executing code that's supposed to run when the login screen is closed without the user actually logging in, so looks like a race condition with the web service. I'll return with the solution when I'm able to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some research to answer the helpful comments on this question, I stumbled across the answer.

I have an event in the application that is designed to close the entire application if the user exits the login page without logging in, since otherwise it would return to the 'home screen' form in an invalid state. It contained the following code, designed to close the application if the user didn't have a token (i.e. had cancelled the page):

Because my login process is asynchronous (code above) when I was stepping through the process in VS, I was getting to the "PostAsJsonAsync" step, and it was closing the application without showing me it was running the 'on close' event. However, unknown to me when testing locally, the code had a race condition where it would jump ahead to the 'close form' bit while still awaiting the web service call, and therefore execute the following code:

```
        private void DoOnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if(GlobalData.SessionKey == null || GlobalData.SessionExpiry <= DateTime.Now)
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }

        }
```

The solution was to remove this event as part of the login process, after the login had been validated, meaning this code would never be called if the user had successfully logged in.